# Error installing mfpdev-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, ibm-mobilefirst, npm-install

I'm trying to install the mobile first CLI, used this command: npm install -g mfpdev-cli

But I'm getting errors. I downgraded my npm to 3.10.6 because I found out that there maybe issues on the latest version.

Error:

```
npm install -g mfpdev-cli

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/elementtree/-/elementtree-0.1.6.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/npmlog/-/npmlog-2.0.2.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/glob/-/glob-7.0.3.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/q/-/q-1.4.1.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/verror/-/verror-1.6.1.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/findup-sync/-/findup-sync-0.3.0.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/ibm-strings/-/ibm-strings-0.1.4.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/underscore/-/underscore-1.8.3.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/glob/-/glob-7.0.3.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/elementtree/-/elementtree-0.1.6.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/npmlog/-/npmlog-2.0.2.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/q/-/q-1.4.1.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/ibm-strings/-/ibm-strings-0.1.4.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/findup-sync/-/findup-sync-0.3.0.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/verror/-/verror-1.6.1.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/underscore/-/underscore-1.8.3.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/elementtree/-/elementtree-0.1.6.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-all/glob/-/glob-7.0.3.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed             

http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/npmlog/-/npmlog-2.0.2.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/findup-sync/-/findup-sync-0.3.0.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/ibm-strings/-/ibm-strings-0.1.4.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/q/-/q-1.4.1.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/verror/-/verror-1.6.1.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/mobile-npm-
all/underscore/-/underscore-1.8.3.tgz

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0

npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mfpdev-
cli"

npm ERR! node v6.6.0

npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND

npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND

npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo


npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com 
visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network 
settings.

npm ERR! network 

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'


npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     /Users/kimnicolemontano/Documents/IBM Mobile First Learning/npm-debug.log
```

I using a macOSX El Capitan Macbook Pro - 10.11.6. I've also turned off the firewall and restarted the router that I'm using.

Comment: It seems that there is an option to install it offline: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/03/31/howto-set-up-an-offline-ibm-mobilefirst-8-0-development-environment/

Will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: a fix has been released to NPM.

This is a known issue with MobileFirst CLI and version 3.10.x of npm. Downgrade to 3.9.x or 3.8.x and the installation will pass successfully.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the offline installation and it worked, albeit with a few adjustments. Will accept this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: To work the update, end up having to also remove and re-add the cli, after the npm downgrade.


`sudo npm uninstall -g mfpdev-cli &&
sudo npm install mfpdev-cli -g`

Comment: No need. A fix has been released yesterday. Simply install normally.

Comment: @IdanAdar I am still getting same error on npm 3.9.0, node 4.6.0

Comment: Nodejs 4? That's not supported. Upgrade node to 5 or 6. Also try clearing your npm cache.

Comment: Cleared npm cache using "npm cache clean" and Upgrade nodejs to version 6.8.1, but still the same error.

Comment: No sure what is the problem. I managed to install both on node and 5. Uninstall the CLI, clear cache, reinstall.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_installing_dev_kit.html?view=embed

This document shows support of Node js 4.0 or later. Let me try uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have successfully installed updated mfpdev-cli using Node JS 6.8.1 and NPM 4.0.0, but after removing and re-adding mfpdev cordova plugin, its version is still showing 8.0.2016080320. I have downloaded latest version that is 8.0.2016101416. Is there anything I have missed?

Comment: Looks like the plugin publication did not finish yet. Until it is you should be able to download it from the console's download center.

Comment: The Cordova plugins are now available online.

Comment: @IdanAdar I am also getting this error installing on OS Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard with node version v7.3.0 and npm version 3.9.0 in both online and downloaded package.